# Mobile Application Random Connection Issue

Tags: android, ios, mobile, genexus

I have a mobile application for Android and iOS that is generated with GenXus.  These apps are used within our customer base for auto service centers and connects to an iSeries (AS/400) for the database backend.  We had to upgrade to the latest version of GeneXus in order to take advanatage of new security requirements set by Apple and Android in order to publish updates.  We made the necessary security settings and recompiled them, nothing major.  Its basically the same code.  Since then our clients experience an error of SQL0204.  We are working with GeneXus on this issue but have resolved nothing.  Has anyone else experienced this error?  We can completely close the application and have the user log back in and all works fine.

Comment: The exact error reads as follows:

com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.JDBCSQLSyntaxErrorException: [SQL0204] WWACST in *LIBL type *FILE not found.

While it seems like the answer is obvious, it isn't.  We are not sure what is causing this as it worked flawlesss prior to the update.

Comment: looks like a simple configuration change.  Add the library the WWACST is in to the job description you are using.